# C# Removing longest words in each line

Tags: c#

I have .txt file.

I have to remove all the longest words for each line.

The main method where I'm looking for longest word is :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds longest word in line
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="eil">Line</param>
    /// <param name="skyr">Punctuation</param>
    /// <returns>Returns longest word for line</returns>
    static string[] RastiIlgZodiEil(string eil, char[] skyr)
    {
        string[] zodIlg = new string[100];

        for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
        {
            zodIlg[k] = " ";
        }

        int kiek = 0;

        string[] parts = eil.Split(skyr,
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        int i = 0;

        foreach (string zodis in parts)
        {
            if (zodis.Length > zodIlg[i].Length)
            {
                zodIlg[kiek] = zodis;
                kiek++;
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
        
        return zodIlg;
    }
```

EDIT : Method that reads the .txt file and uses the previous method to replace line with a new line that is configured (by replacing the word that has to be deleted with an empty string).

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds longest words for each line and then replaces them with 
    /// emptry string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fv">File name</param>
    /// <param name="skyr">Punctuation</param>
    static void RastiIlgZodiFaile(string fv, string fvr, char[] skyr)
    {
        using (var fr = new StreamWriter(fvr, true,
            System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1257)))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fv,
            Encoding.GetEncoding(1257)))
            {
                int n = 0;
                string line;
            
                while (((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null))
                {
                    n++;
                    if (line.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string[] temp = RastiIlgZodiEil(line, skyr);
                        foreach (string t in temp)
                        {
                            line = line.Replace(t, "");
                        }

                        fr.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `zodIlg[i].Length` is always `1` at the time of this comparison `if (zodis.Length > zodIlg[i].Length)` I believe. You should also check the value of `i` against the length of `zodIlg`, you may get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: What is determining the longest words you need to remove? Also is it a sentence for each line? How do you know when your on a new line that isn't part of a sentence? I feel there's another approach to this, but could use some clarification.

Comment: @Codexer The longest word is determined by its length. I might have not understood you properly. Could you be little bit more precise with that question? Yes, it is a sentence for each line I have other method which reads each line, one by one. It is per line.

Comment: @David OK so you want to get the longest word in a line and any other word that matches that length remove it as well, correct?

Comment: @Codexer Yes, exactly.

Comment: @David thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the longest word(s) from each line with:

```
static string RemoveLongestWord(string eil, char[] skyr)
{
    string[] parts = eil.Split(skyr, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int longestLength = parts.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First().Length;
    var longestWords = parts.Where(s => s.Length == longestLength);
    foreach(string word in longestWords)
    {
        eil = eil.Replace(word, "");
    }
    return eil;
}
```

Just pass each line to the function and you'll get that line back with the longest word removed.

Here's an approach that more closely resembles what you were doing before:

```
static string[] RastiIlgZodiEil(string eil, char[] skyr)
{
    List<string> zodIlg = new List<string>();
    string[] parts = eil.Split(skyr, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    int maxLength = -1;
    foreach (string zodis in parts)
    {
        if (zodis.Length > maxLength)
        {
            maxLength = zodis.Length;
        }
    }
    foreach (string zodis in parts)
    {
        if (zodis.Length == maxLength)
        {
            zodIlg.Add(zodis);
        }
    }
    return zodIlg.Distinct().ToArray();
}
```

The first pass finds the longest length.  The second pass adds all word that match that length to a `List<string>`.  Finally, we call `Distinct()` to remove duplicates from the list and return an array version of it.

Comment: Can you further explain what the OP has done wrong with their approach and how this *addresses* their issue?

Comment: This still doesn't resolve my issue. I was able to remove for each line longest word, however, if there're multiple longest words in the same line, they have to be removed as well. That's why I'm trying to use array in order to get to the results.

Comment: Updated code will first find the longest length word, then it will find all words from the line matching that length.  Finally it will return the original line with all those words removed.

Comment: Could you explain these two lines how they work?

"
int longestLength = parts.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First().Length;
var longestWords = parts.Where(s => s.Length == longestLength);
"

Comment: Those two lines are using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries).  See [Query Syntax and Method Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq) for different ways to write them.  One key component is the ability to use [Lamba Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) to tell the operation how to transform or compare each thing in the set.

Comment: "var longestWord = parts.Where(s => s.Length == longestLength);"

What does .Where do exactly? Does this say longestWords = parts.Where // the word's length is the same as longestLength?

Comment: "var longestWord = parts.Where(s => s.Length == longestLength);"  This takes each string in "parts" and passes it to the lambda.  The current string is represented by "s" (this is completely arbitrary, I could have used any variable name here).  If "s" passes the test (returns true) for "s.Length == longestLength", then it is returned as part of the result set.  In the end, the variable "longestWord" will be a set of all the strings in "parts" that passed the lambda test.

Comment: "int longestLength = parts.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First().Length;"  Here we tell parts to sort descending based on the length of each string.  Afterwards, we grab the first string in that set which should be the longest string and obtain the length of it, assigning that to the "longestLength" variable.

Comment: `.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First().Length` can be reduced down to `.Max(s => s.Length)`.

Comment: @David: Simple example: `var allPeopleNamedJohn = allPeople.Where(person => person.Name == "John")`. In essence, `Where` filters your list and only keeps the items that fulfill the criteria (e.g. `Name == "John"`).

Comment: I do wonder if it's more efficient to filter the longest word from `parts` and then restringify it to generate the result, as opposed to string-replacing them in the original string. I'm not 100% sure but I suspect it's more performant, especially when replacing more than one (distinct) word.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution. Read all lines from a file and split each line using a loop. `Aggregate` function is used to get the highest length to filter the data further.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "test.txt"));
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data[i]);

            var split = data[i].Split(' ');
            int length = split.Aggregate((a, b) => a.Length >= b.Length ? a : b).Length;
            data[i] = string.Join(' ', split.Where(w => w.Length < length));

            Console.WriteLine(data[i]);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```